# Action name is null in spring 4 mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my project we are using spring4.When i submit the post request url goes with null

```
<form:form name="authenticatorform"  id="loginForm" action="login.htm">
<input type="submit">
</form:form>
```

When i try to submit the form, the URL is look like this

```
localhost:8080/selva/null 
instead of 
localhost:8080/selva/login.htm
```

I did the view page source it display like below

```
<form:form name="authenticatorform"  id="loginForm" action="null">
<input type="submit">
</form:form>
```

Is there any configuration issue I missed out. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!
Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('9')"
            requires-channel="http" method="POST"  />

        <csrf disabled="false"/>        

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
  <user-service>
    <user name="alex" password="123456789" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    <user name="mkyong" password="123456789" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
  </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>



</beans:beans>
```

Is it the configuration issue?

Comment: I do not think it is a good approach to put .htm file in form submit (action) event, you should call either controller or jsp from their.

Comment: How do you render this form page?

Comment: Using tiles org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver

Comment: If you decided to use Spring, why don't you try Spring Boot which autoconfigures `DispatcherServlet` and ViewResolvers, etc. everything you need for you, so you only need to provide your specific business logic ?)

Comment: check this example, it might help you http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you are overriding the **resolveAction()** method of your FormTag.class
I would suggest you to use a debugger and see where its getting overridden. For me, it was happening in a class where we implemented **RequestDataValueProcessor** Interface and override the **processAction**
action method and set it as null. Just make sure you do not make the same mistake.

Comment: Thanks @user1697113,yes, correct i also made the same mistake. I Correct it